# Select query to find all unique keys from a table where a any word from a list appears in a free text field?

Tags: sql

Looking for a little bit of SQL-foo to help find the most efficient way to do this query.

I have a table with two columns, ID and a small character field (<300 chars). The ID field is not unique, and I would like the result to be a distinct list of ID numbers. I also have an input list of words that I want to query on, say 'foo', 'bar' as the base case. For a result to be valid, it also must have at least one matching row for each word that is input.

What is a clean and efficient way to write this as one query? I am also open to multiple queries if there is no single-query way to execute it efficiently.

Please note that in the specific environment I am working with I cannot use more than 10 subqueries, and I may have 10 or more words provided as input (although I may be able to limit the input to 10 as long as the user is aware of this). Also note that I cannot use the 'IN' clause if it is possible that the list of values in it grows to be larger than a few thousand. I am querying a table with potentially millions of ID-text pairs.

Thanks for any and all advice!

Answer (score 0):

Use a UDF that returns a table:

Consider writing a user-defined function (UDF) that takes a string containing all values that you wish to search for, separated by a delimiter. The UDF would split the data in the string and return it as a table. Then, include the table that the UDF returns as a join on the table in question.

Here's an example: http://everysolution.wordpress.com/2011/07/28/udf-to-split-a-delimited-string-and-return-it-as-a-table/

Answer (score 0):

If that small character field is always one word and you're looking for an exact match with a word in your list, I don't see why the below would not work. That is, if you're looking for IDs with 'foo', do you want only IDs that are 'foo', or might there be 'fooish', which should also be a match? In the latter case this won't work, in the former it should.

The query below assumes:

1. That your 2 column table is called "tbl"
2. That you can put the list of these 'input' words into a table; in my example below this other table is called "othertbl". It should contain however many words you're searching on, and it can be over 1,000 (the exists subquery doesn't have that limitation)
3. As stated before, I am assuming you are looking for exact matches on the 2nd column of "tbl", not partial or fuzzy matches
4. For performance reasons, you'll want to ensure that tbl.wordfield and othertbl.word are indexed (whatever the column names actually are)

-

```
select distinct id
  from tbl
 where exists
 (select 'x' from othertbl where othertbl.word = tbl.wordfield)
```